# .data() in event binding

Tags: jquery, html, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile

Working on a phonegap app with JQ and JQM, and this 1 strange issue really stumped me good.  I could really use all the helps I can get, thanks folks!

Kind of hard to explain but just couldn't get .data() to work similarly in 2 dynamically bind event handlers when this 2 event handlers look almost virtually identical. I must have missed something somewhere.. Sigh..

**HTML**

```
            <ul data-role="listview" id="notelist" data-split-icon="minus" data-split-theme="c">
                <li id="entrytemplate" style="display:none">
                    <a class="btnpopupdetails" href="#" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">
                        <h3>TEMPLATE Faulty lift</h3>
                        <p>TEMPLATE Lift A1, at lobby, Skyscraper Plaza, was reported broken down on 25th Dec 2012</p>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btndelete" href="#" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">Delete</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**JS**

```
// row is a single row from a resultset of a successful sql query

newrow.data('rowid', row.id); // integer

newrow.data('rowtitle', row.txttitle); // text

newrow.data('rowdescription', row.txtdescription); // text

console.log(newrow.data('rowtitle')); // value retrieved and displayed fine!

console.log(newrow.data('rowdescription')); // value retrieved and displayed fine!

newrow.appendTo('#notelist');

newrow.find('h3').text(row.txttitle);

newrow.find('p').text(row.txtdescription);


newrow.find('.btnpopupdetails').click(function() {

  selectedrow = $(this).parent();

  selectedrowid = selectedrow.data('rowid');

  selectedrowtitle = selectedrow.data('rowtitle');

  selectedrowdscription = selectedrow.data('rowdescription');

  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowid')); // "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object"

  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowtitle')); // "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object"

  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowdescription')); // "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object"
});


newrow.find('.btndelete').click(function() {

  selectedrow = $(this).parent();

  selectedrowid = selectedrow.data('rowid');

  selectedrowtitle = selectedrow.data('rowtitle');

  selectedrowdscription = selectedrow.data('rowdescription');

  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowid')); // value retrieved and displayed fine!

  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowtitle')); // value retrieved and displayed fine!

  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowdescription')); // value retrieved and displayed fine!
```

Comment: Without a working example it is difficult to point it out.. Can you create a fiddle .??

Comment: thanks for helping and the editing, folks, really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea what might be going on:, when jQM enhances the markup of a link `<a>` in an `<li>` it actually encases it in 2 div's.  Inspect your markup after the page has loaded to confirm this.  If I load your markup into an `<li>`, the first `<a>` comes up encased in 2 divs, the second is a direct child of the `<li>` so this would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

This means that when you indicate `selectedrow = $(this).parent();` I suspect it's indicating the div that contains your `<a class="btnpopupdetails">` not the `<li>` to which you've attached the data;

Instead try replacing that line with this: `selectedrow = $(this).closest('li');` or give your `<li>` a new class and use `$(this).closest('.newClass')`

Give that a shot and let me know how that works out. Should look like this (That's right 1 handler for both elements):

```
newrow.find('.btnpopupdetails, .btndelete').click(function() {  
  selectedrow = $(this).closest('li');    // THIS HAS CHANGED!
  selectedrowid = selectedrow.data('rowid');
  selectedrowtitle = selectedrow.data('rowtitle');
  selectedrowdscription = selectedrow.data('rowdescription');
  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowid')); // "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object"
  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowtitle')); // "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object"
  console.log(selectedrow.data('rowdescription')); // "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object"
});
```

Comment: Yes.. $(this).closest('li') nailed it! Thank you very much for the help! Probably need to revisit some of the references and check out some of the JQM's not too obvious under the hood operation.. :-)